# set Initial state from iteration of array and declare variables at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I am trying to replicate some of my old work to create a new project using hooks

```js
FIELDS = [
    { id: 'first_name', label: 'First Name', required: true },
    { id: 'last_name', label: 'Last Name', required: true },
    { id: 'company', label: 'Company', required: false },
    { id: 'phone', label: 'Phone', required: false },
    { id: 'address1', label: 'Address', required: true },
    { id: 'address2', label: 'Apartment, suite, etc. (optional)', required: false },
    { id: 'city', label: 'City', required: true },
    { id: 'country', label: 'Country', required: true },
    { id: 'province', label: 'Region', required: false },
    { id: 'zip', label: 'ZIP/Postal code', required: false }
];

this.FIELDS.forEach(f => this.state[f.id] = props.address == undefined ? '' : props.address[f.id]);
```

How do I replicate this in hooks

Comment: React state is expected to be immutable.You shouldn't modify this.state directly so that's the problem with this snippet for starters.

Comment: This is incorrect, you don't set state values directly, you use `setState`.  And the equivalent with hooks is `useState`,  the docs on which go over what is and basic use cases. Plus without any context for your code it's kind of hard to tell what it *should* be

Comment: what r u even trying todo in the last line?

Comment: I am trying to create a form with default props values set. I am using this array for that. I an going to render these values to input fields.